# WebApi method is unable to bind to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, http-post

Basically I'm trying to create a method in my webapi controller:

The method looks like this(the method body is relevant):

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CpaLead([FromBody]CpaLeadVM model)
{
```

Here's the class declaration of the object being passed:

```
public class CpaLeadVM
{
    public string UserIp = "";
    public string UserCountry = "";
    public double Earn = 0.0;
    public string SurveyType = "";
}
```

The thing is; when I send a post request to the method, the model is always null.
The post request has the following data:

```
UserIp=hello
Earn=44.4
UserCountry=denmark
SurveyType=free
```

Shouldn't it be able to bind to the model or am I missing something here?

Comment: How you are trying do HttpPost? Share that code also.

Comment: You probably meant to say "the method body is IRRELEVANT" (since you're not showing it).

Comment: Also check if your model state has any errors...this can contain some useful information.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the "properties" you are trying to bind to are fields and not actual properties. The model binders and formatters in Web Api doesn't look at fields. If you change your model to:

```
public class CpaLeadVM
{
    public CpaLeadVm()
    {
        UserIp = "";
        UserCountry = "";
        Earn = 0.0;
        SurveyType = "";
    }

    public string UserIp {get;set;}
    public string UserCountry {get;set;}
    public double Earn {get;set;}
    public string SurveyType {get;set;}
}
```

Your binding will work. As a side note, the `[FromBody]` attribute on your action is redundant since non-primitive values are bound from the request body by default.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, you can only get a single value from the body, which must be sent as "=value". See this article for more info
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

I'm not sure, but I think you could create your own model binder, which parses the body into your class. Another approach is to use JSON. Read more about that here
[ASP.NET MVC 4 Post FromBody Not Binding From JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573526/asp-net-mvc-4-post-frombody-not-binding-from-json)